# SwiftyJSON Alamofire How to return what you got?

Tags: json, swift

How to return what you got?Excuse me, novice, I understand only.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UWC0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGmyR.png)

Comment: You should always copy your code into your question, instead of adding a screenshot. It just makes it difficult to test your code when we need to rewrite it.

Comment: You are missing either concept or vocabulary/key words to do a proper search on your issue: "Async (or asynchrone) + Swift + Closure"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alamofire.request` is an asynchronous task, so any code written after this is most likely going to be executed before the task is complete. There are a few ways of doing what you want, but since you haven't provided much information, I have just moved the `JSON` inside the closure. So you should get something to print out.

```
Alamofire.request("https://...").responseJSON { (response) in

    // Inside this closure is where you receive your JSON

    if let value = response.value {

        let json = JSON(value)

        let title = json["posts", 3, "title"].stringValue

        print("Title:", title)
    }
}

// Any code after this request will most likely be executed before
// the request has completed because it is done asynchronously.
```

---

This is another way that might work better for you.

I understand that you are a beginner and these kinds of operations can be quite complex. You need to understand the order at which code get executed, and how variables work. You are getting that error because `swiftyJsonVar` is declared in a block that is not accessible to code in the `viewDidLoad`. I suggest you learn about `multi-threading` and other `asynchronous` tasks and probably learn how to declare and use variables properly.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    load { (json) in

        if let json = json {

            let title = json["posts", 3, "title"].stringValue

            print("Title:", title)
        }
    }
}

func load(completion: @escaping (JSON?) -> Void){

    Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { (response) in //https://...

        var json: JSON?

        if let value = response.value {

            json = JSON(value)
        }

        completion(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is clear to me. Under my question I meant: how to handle the fact that json received from Alamofire.request. For example it will write error(does not see the variable):

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        load()
        var oneTitle = swiftyJsonVar["posts", 3, "title"].stringValue
        print("Title: " + oneTitle)
        
        
    }
    func load(){
        
        Alamofire.request("https://gg").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            
        }
        
        }
        
    }`

Comment: I understand that the compiler executes the program from the top down. But the question is, can I get json from Alamofire.request and write it into a variable declared in the program. Ie, that would then use the received data.
Thanks for the answers, I really appreciate them.

Comment: What I have shown above is how you are suposed handle these kinds of requests. Also in this case, the code doesn't really run top to bottom, because `Alamofire` requests are done `asynchronously`. You need to understand how that works. I suggest looking at other `Alamofire` questions on this site.